# Eclipse Gerrit Connector credentials are invalidated on individual review retrieval

Tags: eclipse, authentication, eclipse-plugin, gerrit, mylyn

I am trying to setup Gerrit code review in my eclipse workspace. I configured the repository. The 'Validate Settings' shows a note mentioning that I have logged in with valid credentials and also my name is displayed as on the repository server.

The list of all the reviews is listed in the beginning. As I try to open an individual review to view it in detail, I get the following error-

[image: Credentials error]

I see a bug open on eclipse bugzilla [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468985). It is the same issue but I see there has not been any solution to it.

Does anybody have any ideas on how do I solve it?

*P.S.: I am facing the same issue on GitEye as well.*